# How can I create an entirely new repository from an existing repository's branch?

Tags: svn, import, migrate

I tried to search around for this but think I only came up with results for copying the entire repository and/or trunk. In my case, I don't want to copy `trunk` from my existing repository - I only care about one branch.

However, there may be an issue because this branch was a `svn cp` of `trunk` at one point in time. Will this be an issue or can I somehow avoid it?

So basically I need:

```
existing repository
     **branches/beta** ( this was copied from trunk a long time ago)
     trunk <-- 

new repository
     **trunk** ( from branches/beta )
```

Comment: Any `svndumpfilter` search will give a lot of samples on first page, even here, on SO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `svnrdump dump` or `svnadmin dump | svndumpfilter` in order to get portable dump from any part of repository (workflow is common, only details are different).

You can use `svnadmin load --parent-dir` or `svnrdump load` in order to load dump into new repository with any new "mount-point".

But, AFAICR, using pure SVN-tools without handwork in dump-file, you can not remove|change relative path of transferred in dump files (in your case it means restored dump, loaded to `/trunk`, will create `branches/beta` inside it), which you'll have to fix with additional commit(s) after `svn mv` in new repository

**Note**

With HG-in-the-middle you can get correctly rebased folder into the root of repo without additional commits in target, but - for the cost of addinional (local) VCS